# Account Name showing ??? in Sailpoint instead of account Name

Tags: sailpoint

I am working on JDBC provisioning and even if provisioning is working fine i.e. record is getting inserted in database table, the account name is coming as ??? and account status coming as deleted.

I already have provisioning policy in place and provisioning plan also retrieving correct values.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check that you have set the same value of `Identity Attribute` in the `Name` field of your provisioning policy . If the value is different then this issue will occur.

Tip: You can set different account name by picking up any field name from your schema and setting it in Name attribute in Identity Attribute and Provisioning Policy.

Comment: if you are down voting this answer please add correct answer from your perspective or at least comment is required. The above answer is correct and its working in my case.